# What does sup mean?

Tags: notation

I found this formula regarding calories burned:

> Rate per Pound (Cal/lb-min)=A+BV+CV.sup.2 +KDV.sup.3 where:
>
> V=Running Speed (mph)--limited to a minimum of 3 mph and a maximum of
>   14 mph
>
> A=0.0395
>
> B=0.00327
>
> C=0.000455
>
> D=[0.00801(W/154).sup.0.425 ]/W
>
> W=Weight (lbs)
>
> K=0 or 1 (0=Treadmill; 1=Outdoors)

But what do the `.sup.2` and `.sup.3`stand for? What does it mean?

Comment: I expect it is meant to indicate that what follows is an exponent. So `(W/154).sup.0.425` means $(W/154)^{0.425}$; `KDV.sup.3` maans $KDV^3$, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means *superscript* (usually an exponent). For example, the first equation is supposed to read:
$$\text{Rate per pound (Cal/lb-min)} = A + BV + CV^2 + KDV^3$$

In my opinion, nobody really writes like that unless they have no way to insert a superscript, which I suspect is the case.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I, as a programmer, would have have gone for `pow` for 'to the power'. Ah well, thanks!

Comment: Presumably, that .sup. notation corresponds to some computer language.  Back from the days when you didn't get a ^ character to use.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it means $CV^2$ and $KDV^3$...